# Is it possible to connect my hp laptop localhost IP to in my MacBook through localhost IP address?

Tags: localhost

I have two laptop
first is HP and second is MacBook
Now I want to use HP localhost IP to in my MacBook through localhost IP address
Is it possible?

Comment: See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#section-3.2.1.3

Answer (score 1):

No. `localhost` specifically means "the computer that is making the request", `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` on the HP will always be answered by the HP. If you want to use the IP address of the Macbook to allow the HP to see services on the Macbook, that is another and completely different question.